# Managing Wordpress Theme

Tags: theme-development, themes

A Wordpress theme has following components:

- theme.zip file
- demo-content.xml
- PSD.zip file (contains files such as icon-blog.psd, icon-home.psd,
  integrity-blog.psd, ... renew-home.psd)

Using WP Admin (WP Backend) I have managed to upload theme.zip file. Using WP Importer I have managed to upload demo content. However, what do I do with PSD files? I would like to add that the current frontend looks very basic. And I assume PSD files serve to enrich frontend. But how do I use them? Where do I "import" them? How do I do it?

Answer (score 2):

PSD files are typically included with premium themes as an extra to allow you to customize the image assets. You have to open those files in Photoshop, edit them, and export new versions to replace the png, gif, or jpg assets that came with the theme. There's nothing in WordPress core that deals with PSD files, and the specific details of how the PSD files map to the assets in your theme are specific to that theme. If explicit instructions for what to do with them did not come with your theme, that's a question you'll have to ask whomever developed your theme.

Comment: Still remains the same question - where to integrate them? Is there any tutorial/video where that's explained? If I understood you correctly the input in the process are PSD files, and output PNG, JPEG, and GIF files. Right?

Comment: it's specific to your theme, there is no standard. the images are likely referenced in some theme CSS file, but how they're linked or named or used or their format isn't answerable without looking at the files in your particular theme.